# Factory_girl deprecation for rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-upgrade

I'm currently upgrading my rails application from rails 4 to rails 5. Is it necessary to change from Factory_girl to Factory_bot? What will happen if I proceed with a deprecation warning? further, I might be upgrading that application to rails 6, so would factory_girl work for rails 6?

Comment: The change it's just a naming change, it doesn't change any functionality. Anyway, the change is so easy it makes no sense to stick with the old one https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/4-9-0-stable/UPGRADE_FROM_FACTORY_GIRL.md

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have changed it to factory_bot in all files. However, I'm getting an error that the Factory is not registered. Also, is it compulsory to have rails_helper file? It seems that I don't have it in my old running application on rails 4.                                                                                                      
 Error: Request should create a valid object
     Failure/Error: user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
     
     KeyError:
       Factory not registered: "user"

Comment: Usually the rails_helper file includes tests configuration specific to rails (while test_helper includes not rails related test configuration). I'm not sure why you don't have that. Are you using factory_bot or factory_bot_rails?

Comment: We are using factory_bot_rails

Answer (score 0):

[`FactoryGirl` was renamed to `FactoryBot`](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/factory_bot) in October 2017. (The original name was based on some [inside joke/pop culture reference](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/issues/921#issuecomment-231735985), which some argued was a poor decision.)

This has got nothing to do with upgrading rails, and everything to do with upgrading `factory_girl`/`factory_bot`.

Use the new name. It makes no sense to keep the old name - and regardless, your code will break at some point when updating versions, if you don't perform the rename.

The change is quite straightforward, and there are various guides people have written about the upgrade, such as [this](https://fuzzyblog.io/blog/rails/2018/04/19/converting-from-factorygirl-to-factorybot.html).

Essentially, all you need to do is:

1. Rename `factory_girl` and/or `factory_girl_rails` in the `Gemfile`, to `factory_bot` and `factory_bot_rails`.
2. Rename any mention of `FactoryGirl` to `FactoryBot`. (You could use `git grep` to ensure nothing is missed.)